# cannot find symbol symbol : constructor A() location: class A

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, constructor

```
class A {
     A(int i){    
        System.out.println("A(int)");
     }
 }

class B1 extends A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A ob=new A(2);  
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, please add a question in your content also. Plain code, might be clear here, but it will not always be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have declared a *1-arg* `constructor` in `class A`. So, *compiler* does not provide a *default 0-arg* `constructor`.

Now, in `class B1`, you have not defined any `constructor`, so *compiler* adds a *default*  *0-arg* `constructor` in that class, which looks like this: -

```
public B1() {
    super();
}
```

As you can see, *Compiler* adds a `super()` call to invoke the `0-arg constructor` of the `super class`, which is `class A`, in this case.

Now, since your `class A`, does not have any *0-arg* `constructor`, hence the error.

---

**So, either** you can add a `0-arg constructor` in your class A: -

```
public A() {

}
```

This will solve the issue.

---

**Or,** add a `0-arg constructor` in your `class B1` explicitly, and add a `super()` call to the `1-arg constructor` of `class A`: -

```
public B1() {
    super(0);  // Or any value
}
```

---

But, the problem in the 2nd solution will be that, from every constructor in your `class B1`, you would have to invoke the `1-arg constructor` of `class A` explicitly. As soon as you miss one, you will get a `compiler` error immediately.

So, I would suggest to go with the `1st option`. Add a `0-arg constructor` in `class A`. And you are all good.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to define a constructor in the subclass, like this:

```
class B1 extends A{

    public B1(int x){
       super(x);
    }

    ...
}
```

OR

Add a default constructor in class A.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class A {

    A(){
    }
    A(int i){    
        System.out.println("A(int)");
     }
 }

class B1 extends A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A ob=new A(2);  
    }
}
```

> You have to give the default constructor in this case,because the
>   A(int i) hides it and when you make the object of class a it shows
>   error.The above my code works fine.

Comment: Actually the code you posted will work fine. But the explanation you gave is quite confusing. It conveys that, creating an instance of class A using 1-arg constructor requires a 0-arg constructor also. Which is not the case. See my answer for better explanation/